# Checking validity of formulas in first-order logic

Tags: logic

*Given four formulas in first order logic. Which of the following formulas are* not *valid? (In logic a proposition is valid if it never evaluates to $\bot$.)*

1. $(\exists x P(x)\to Q)\to (\forall x (P(x)\to Q))$
2. $((\neg P\to Q)\wedge(P\to R))\to (\neg P\to R)$
3. $(\exists x(P(x)\to Q(x)))\leftrightarrow  (\forall x P(x)\to\exists x P(x))$
4. $(\forall xP(x)\to Q)\to (\forall x (P(x)\to Q))$

According to proof by negation, for example if we negate formula in $1$ then we get $\bot$, as a result this shows that $1$ is valid. Instructor said only $4$ is not valid, but I think both $2$ and $4$ are not valid according to proof by negation.

Comment: This seems more suitable to [math.se].

Comment: I suspect you had a typo in your above formula 3. where the last term should be $Q(x)$ (not $P(x)$), then it's true, which can be easily derived from prenex normal form's [implication rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form#Implication). The intuition 2. is false is that there's no possible implication link from $\neg P$ to $R$ from the outermost antecedent. The intuition 4. is false is that $\forall x P(x)$ is much stricter/stronger than $\forall x(P(x)..)$ logically while ranging over same domain of discourse, so it's easier to be false, and thus conditional vacuously holds...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the following heuristic comes from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3291828/how-to-determine-the-validity-of-statements-in-first-order-logic-is-there-a-gen?rq=1)

> Heuristic: To try to determine whether $\phi$ is valid: If the answer's not
> obvious, look for an interpretation where $\phi$ is false.

So try to proof by negation. Consider $1:$

Let
\begin{gather*} 
\phi\equiv(\exists xP(x)\to Q )\to(\forall x(P(x)\to Q)).
\end{gather*}

Now negate $\phi$ then we have:
\begin{gather*} 
\neg\phi\equiv \neg(\neg(\exists xP(x)\to Q )\vee(\forall x(P(x)\to Q)))\equiv (\exists xP(x)\to Q )\wedge \neg(\forall x(P(x)\to Q))\equiv (\forall x\neg P(x)\vee Q )\wedge (\exists x(P(x) \wedge \neg Q))
\end{gather*}

so after elimination of quantifiers:

\begin{gather*} 
 \neg P(x)\vee Q 
\end{gather*}
\begin{gather*} 
P(C_1)
\end{gather*}
\begin{gather*} 
\neg Q 
\end{gather*}

oblivious that if we use resolution, and resolve each clause we achieve $\bot$.

As a result we can say $1$ is valid.

$2$ is not valid, you can use above method or if we set

\begin{gather*} 
Q\equiv \top
\end{gather*}
\begin{gather*} 
 P\equiv R\equiv \bot
\end{gather*}

as a result $2$ is $\bot$.

Repeat idea that used in $1$ for $3$:(as you know from logic, $A\leftrightarrow B\equiv (A\to B) \wedge  (B\to A)$) so we have:

\begin{gather*} 
 \neg(((\exists x(P(x)\to Q(x)) \to (\forall xP(x)\to \exists xP(x)))
\end{gather*}
\begin{gather*} 
\wedge
\end{gather*}
\begin{gather*} 
(\forall xP(x)\to \exists xP(x)) \to ((\exists x(P(x)\to Q(x))  ))
\end{gather*}

After applying  negation:
\begin{gather*} 
\equiv
\end{gather*}

\begin{gather*} 
 (((\exists x(\neg P(x)\vee Q(x)) \wedge (\forall xP(x)\wedge \forall  x\neg P(x)))
\end{gather*}
\begin{gather*} 
\vee
\end{gather*}
\begin{gather*} 
(\exists x\neg P(x)\vee \exists xP(x)) \wedge  ((\forall x(P(x)\wedge \neg Q(x))  ))
\end{gather*}
Eliminate quantifiers:

\begin{gather*} 
 (\neg P(C_1)\vee Q(C_1)) \wedge (P(x)\wedge\neg P(x))
\end{gather*}
\begin{gather*} 
\vee
\end{gather*}
\begin{gather*} 
(\neg P(C_2)\vee P(C_3)) \wedge  (P(x)\wedge \neg Q(x)  ))
\end{gather*}
As you know

\begin{gather*} 
 (\neg P(C_1)\vee Q(C_1)) \wedge (P(x)\wedge\neg P(x))\equiv \bot
\end{gather*}

So we have:

\begin{gather*} 
 \bot
\end{gather*}
\begin{gather*} 
\vee
\end{gather*}
\begin{gather*} 
(\neg P(C_2)\vee P(C_3)) \wedge  (P(x)\wedge \neg Q(x)  ))
\end{gather*}

\begin{gather*} 
\equiv
\end{gather*}
\begin{gather*} 
(\neg P(C_2)\vee P(C_3)) \wedge  (P(x)\wedge \neg Q(x)  ))
\end{gather*}
As a result above formula can't equal to $\top$ because we can't resolve some clauses to get $\bot$. So $3$ isn't valid.

$4$ remain as exercise, if you follow described approach for other options, you can see $4$ is not valid.